How to show that the field $\mathbb{F}_2(t^{\frac{1}{3}})$ does not contain a third root of unity
I want to find a non-normal extension in characteristic p. The following extension is not normal :
$$\mathbb{F}_2(t)\subset \mathbb{F}_2(t^{\frac{1}{3}})$$
It's minimal polynomial is : $X^3-t$ and it's roots are $t^{\frac{1}{3}},\zeta_3 t^{\frac{1}{3}}, \zeta_3^2t^{\frac{1}{3}}$
How do I show that $\mathbb{F}_2(t^{\frac{1}{3}})$ does not contain a third root of unity?
I tried the following. If $\zeta_3$ is contained in $\mathbb{F}_2(t^{\frac{1}{3}})$, then there exists $f(t^{\frac{1}{3}}),g(t^{\frac{1}{3}})\in \mathbb{F}_p(t^{\frac{1}{3}})$ with :
$\zeta=\frac{f(t^{\frac{1}{3}})}{g(t^{\frac{1}{3}})}$ which implies $\left(\frac{f(t^{\frac{1}{3}})}{g(t^{\frac{1}{3}})}\right)^3=1$
How does this imply that $\frac{f}{g} \in \mathbb{F}_2$. And if that is the case then $\mathbb{F}_2$ does not contain a third root of unity which makes this extension not normal.

Compare with, say, this proof.

$\Bbb{F}_2(t^{1/3})$ is isomorphic to $\Bbb{F}_2(t)$. And the latter does not contain a third roots of unity. Follows from for example uniqueness of factorization of polynomials (and the fact that $\Bbb{F}_2$ has not third roots of unity).

@DietrichBurde I did not understand that proof. I only need to proof that the root of unity must be in $\mathbb{F}_2$
